# How come my CAGradientLayer is not displaying?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation, cagradientlayer

I need to know what i am doing wrong. Im literally copying and pasting this into my code and the gradient is not displaying.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIView *gradient_view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient_layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    [gradient_layer setFrame:gradient_view.bounds];

    gradient_layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    gradient_layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);

    UIColor *top_color = [UIColor redColor];
    UIColor *bottom_color = [UIColor blueColor];
    [gradient_layer setColors:@[top_color,bottom_color]];
    [gradient_view.layer addSublayer:gradient_layer];
    [self.view addSubview:gradient_view];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

It just displays a white screen. Can anyone help me to figure out what the issue is. Cause its really bugging me now.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to kick yourself :)

Gradient layer requires CGColorRef, not UIColor:

```
CGColorRef topRef = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
CGColorRef botRef = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

[gradient_layer setColors:@[(__bridge id)topRef, (__bridge id)botRef]];
```